# Terraform: using the vsphere provider in an offline windows environment

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I want to use the terraform vsphere provider on a windows machine that cannot access the internet. I have downloaded terraform (v0.14.9) from [here](https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html) and the latest vsphere provider (v1.25.0) from [here](https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-vsphere) and copied these to the offline machine. However, I don't know how to then configure Terraform so it refers to my offline vsphere provider when calling init, plan, apply and destroy commands.

I have saved the "terraform.exe" in the C:/tools directory and setup my environment variables.

1. I have tried saving the vsphere provider to `C:/tools/terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vsphere/terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.25.0_x4.exe` and added the following to the top of my tf file:

```
    terraform {
       required_providers {
           vsphere = {
               source  = "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vsphere"
               version = "~> 1.25.0"
            }
        }
     }
```

2. I have tried saving it to an arbitrary folder (`C:/tools/plugins/terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.25.0_x4.exe`) and referring to it in the init command:
   `terraform init -input=false -plugin-dir=C:/tools/plugins)`

Attempt one tries to connect to the internet (which fails) and attempt two gives the following fail response:

> Initializing the backend...
>
> Initializing provider plugins...
> Finding hashicorp/vsphere versions matching "~> 1.25.0"...
>
> Error: Failed to query available provider packages
>
> Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/vsphere: provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vsphere was not found in any of the search locations
>
> -C:/tools/plugins

So I expanded my directory for the vsphere plugin as follows:
`C:/tools/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vsphere/terraform-provider-vsphere_v1.25.0_x4.exe`

But it still does not work and presents the same error message?

Answer (score 0):

follow in bellow - https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-14.html
using in cli using terraform : type terraform upgrade.

Comment: or add terraform version -   version ="~> "1.25.0"

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am unsure what you are instructing me to do? why and where do I have to type "terraform upgrade"? I added the tilda arrow but it has done nothing. (Sorry but I am new to using terraform)

Comment: first update your main.tf and type terraform init in CLI

Comment: Hi , yes. in your cli terraform upgrade.